# How can I download and install "DC Universe Online" on a hard drive other than the basic hard drive of my computer?

Tags: dc-universe-online

My computer is quite old.  It's three years old, and I have no space on my hard drive at all.  However, I'd like to install the Steam version of Warner Brothers' well-known online game "DC Universe Online".  I know that there's a non-Steam version also available, but as I said before I have no space on my computer.  This means that the only "DC Universe" version that I am able to play is the Steam one, and that's because I can install the game on another Hard Drive!

The problem is that although I have a Steam account, I cannot find a Steam version of the game. The main problem is that I have no space on the basic hard drive of my computer.  How do I either find the Steam version or install the other version on a different hard drive?

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. You can install the game without Steam to another Hard Drive than your own. You will need to go ahead and declare to the game installer that you want to install the game in another drive.

Answer (score 2):

In your steam client, under Steam -> settings -> Downloads, click on "Steam Library Folders", then add a new library folder on the new drive.

Comment: Is there a "DC Universe Online game " available on steam ?

Comment: Yes. Search for "DC Universe Online" in the steam client.

Comment: I did that but I found nothing at all. Are you sure that there's still a "DC Universe Online" version on steam ?

Comment: http://store.steampowered.com/app/24200/ There's something odd going on with the search field right now -- if you start typing "DC U" then it appears in the suggestion dropdowns, but if you hit enter it finds nothing matching "DC U"

Comment: I think I found the problem , I clicked on the link and a message appears which states that "This item is currently unavailable in your region"  If I changed the language on steam,would that help me with my problem ?

Comment: @LeiaOrganaSkywalker No, since Steam determines your location via your IP and it is against the SSA to use VPN or other tools to mask your location.

Comment: Surely, even though you've selected a destination outside your local disk, it still uses some space on your local disk?  Is there a way to make it completely portable?